# Viewflow Signal for New tasks?

Tags: python, django-viewflow

I am looking to announce in my slack channels whenever a new task becomes available.

Looking at the src, it seems like there is only a signal whenever a task is started.

How can I create a signal when a task becomes available?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using signals to interact within your own application is a bad design decision.

You can implement same functionality more explicit by implementing a custom node, that would perform an callback on create

```
class MyFlow(Flow):
    ...

    approve = (
        MyView(flow_views.UpdateProcessView, fields=['approved'])
        .onCreate(this.send_notification)
        .Next(this.check_approve)
    )

...
```

You can handle create action by overriding the node activation class `activate` method

The viewflow custom node sample could be helpful as a reference for custom node implementation https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/customnode/nodes.py